# flowgraph exit with error code -11 after start

Tags: python, python-2.7, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am a gnuradio 3.7.13.4 using WXGUI and a rtl sdr donggle on debian 4.19.28-2.

I tried to install gr-lora, since that i can't launch any flowgraph on gnuradio without having the -11 error code.

First, i assume that gr-lora has some bug and unistall it, then I tried to purge and reinstall gnuradio but the result is always the same.
So i have generated topblock.py and run

```
python topblock.py
```

But it ends with a segmentation fault.

In order to understand the problem, i create a simple flowgraph with an osmocom source and a fft sink.
Therefore, i get some trace when i launch the flow graph which indicates there is something fishy :

> Generating: '/home/nicolas/top_block.py'
>
> Executing: /usr/bin/python2 -u /home/nicolas/top_block.py
>
> WARNING: Config file '/etc/gnuradio/conf.d/gnuradio-runtime.conf' failed to parse:
> std::exception
> Skipping it
> WARNING: Config file '/etc/gnuradio/conf.d/gnuradio-runtime.conf' failed to parse:
> std::exception
> Skipping it
> WARNING: Config file '/etc/gnuradio/conf.d/gnuradio-runtime.conf' failed >to parse:
> std::exception
> Skipping it
>
> Done (return code -11)

Comment: hm, sounds like you've got a damaged config file. mind adding the full contents of "/etc/gnuradio/conf.d/gnuradio-runtime.conf" to your question in verbatim?

Comment: (also, replace WX with QT. GNU Radio 3.8 removes WX.)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I found out that my debian is buster/sid version, plus i have some other issues with packages. I will  migrate to a stretch debian version and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I'd really also simply check that file and see whether it looks OK. Might be that something modified it and broke it underway.

Comment: I've switched to debian strectch and after a installation everything seems to work fine. Before delete my old OS i checked .conf and it looked normal...